# Restore the crontab

Tags: linux, cron

I have accidentally entered crontab -r instead of crontab -e and my crontab got removed and when i type crontab -l it is showing "no crontab for root".

This is the previous result of my crontab -l

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
0 0 * * * rsync /etc/ /var/backups/etc/ -arP
0 0 * * * rsync /opt/ /var/backups/opt/ -arP
```

Please can anyone guide me on how to undo this and restore my crontab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use crontab -e to edit (and install) a new crontab.

```
$ crontab -e
```

Copy & paste the previous crontab into editor, save and exit. The new/old crontab will be installed.

More often than not, default editor for root is vi. If you are having trouble using it, here are the basic commands to accomplish this task:

1. Press 'i' to begin entering or pasting text ("insert")
2. Enter or paste the crontab
3. Press Esc, then ':wq', then Enter ("write", "quit")